# Jquery plugin Galleria won't load in iframe until it's refreshed. Why is this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, iframe, galleria

I've been having crazy hell with getting Galleria to load in an initially hidden iframe without manually refreshing said iframe.

I am getting an error in Error Console from galleria.js, reporting 'Width & Height not found', so I've tried to set them manually about five different ways, including:

```
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');

    $('#gallery').galleria({
        height: 450,
width: 1024
    });
</script>
```

I've got a modified script (Slicker Show & Hide) that vanishes the iframe before the page  loads, and I think this may be causing the problem, but I can't seem to find a way around it - something like making it appear offscreen, and then when called hide, move onscreen and show?

I also have a problem with my qTips not loading all the time. Is this all to do with timings or something? Would a pre-loader or something help fix this?

The site is live [here](http://portiaab.com/rainbowwhitebg1024.html)

If anyone could please give me a hand, I'd love to get this set up so I can move on!

Cheers

edit: or, if that's not possible, how can I force the frame to refresh the first time I 'show' it?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  Made a few stabs at the issue but both attempts were incorrect.  Removed incorrect code so as not to confuse people.

Edit put the iframe wireup inside document.ready to ensure that it is on the page prior to attempting to wire this up.

replace '#iframeId' with # + id of your iframe.

Comment: @antonlavey Thanks anton - unfortunately the iframe still stays blank until refresh, and then on refresh galleria is now broken!

Comment: if i get it to load the theme first then it is unbroken, but still blank until refresh...

Comment: try out my edit.  It should trigger when the iframe is loaded.

Comment: Closer! Now the images load without refreshing, but display on top of each other (ie Galleria isn't working properly)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems I get the same effect by not loading Galleria at all - that is, the second suggestion seems to break Galleria and therefore allows the images to load normally :( I am adding this code into the child iframe, so would it be able to call from within a frame using it's own ID ?

Comment: If you have control over the page that the iframe loads I would move your galleria wireup to that page inside of a $(document).ready().  I tend to avoid iframes if possible so my experience with them is limited.

Comment: I do have control over it, but if I move the galleria code to the parent page then I can't get Galleria to load.

Comment: If there's any other way (instead of iframes) to position different sets of content over the background image while still being able to interact with the menu on the main page, I'm willing to try recoding!

Comment: You can do that with html/css I have done that on a few projects if you can put an example on a public page I can take a look at it to see if I can get you going

Comment: I was thinking of abandoning Galleria sadly, and trying AnythingSlider, since that seems much more iframe-friendly...

Comment: Took a look at that page and it looks like you have it working with anything slider.  Let me know if you need any help

Comment: I wish it were the case, but it only seems to work for me again when I refresh! Why oh why could this be? :(